# Is there a way to automatically update git submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I currently have a repo on github that contains a submodule. In order to update the submodule in any place I do a `git pull` to pull the main repo but have to do a `git pull origin master` from the directory of the submodule in order to update the submodule. Is there any way to update the submodule automatically when I do a `git pull` in the main project repo?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `man git pull`:

```
git pull --recurse-submodules=yes
```

```
   --[no-]recurse-submodules[=yes|on-demand|no]
       This option controls if new commits of all populated
       submodules should be fetched and
       updated, too (see git-config(1) and gitmodules(5)).

       If the checkout is done via rebase, local submodule commits 
       are rebased as well.

       If the update is done via merge, 
       the submodule conflicts are resolved and checked out.
```